# I can't connect to Instagram using instabot

Tags: python, python-3.x, instagram-api

I want to write a simple echo "bot" on instagram using instabot because it has a method that can help me. But I always get a 429 error. I'm trying to do this due 2 days, so that's not my broken IP. I also used VPN to connect, and it didn't work too.
*Does anyone know anything about it?*

That's my code:

```
# Program to send message
# on Instagram using Python.
 
# importing Bot form instabot library.
from instabot import Bot
 
# Creating bot variable.
bot = Bot()
 
# Login using bot.
bot.login(username="my_username",
          password="my_password")
 
# Make a list of users
urer_ids = ["some_usr", "another_usr"]
 
# Message
text = "hi)"
 
# Sending messages
bot.send_messages(text, urer_ids)
```

Well, I tried to reinstall instabot, delete *config *directory. And of course, I tried to wait (it didn't help).

Comment: Could you include the full error message

Comment: 2023-06-06 21:55:43,956 - ERROR - Request returns 429 error!
2023-06-06 21:55:43,957 - WARNING - That means 'too many requests'. I'll go to sleep for 5 minutes.

Comment: After 5 minutes - 10, after 10 - 15. Bit after 15 programm is dead...

Answer (score 0):

First check that you put the correct Instagram username and password in the 'bot.login() ' function. I have been unable to make a connection in the past due to typing mistakes.

If the username and password is correct, ensure that you don't exceed Instagram's API usage limitations by limiting the number of requests you make in a short period. Excessive or suspicious activity can trigger temporary or permanent blocks.

Finally, ensure that you have the latest version of the Instabot library via the following command:

```
pip install --upgrade instabot
```

Comment: I have a 429 error. That means "Too many requests". I dont think that it's really mean. About upgrade -> I'm on the latest version

Comment: This is good advice, but it isn't really an _answer_.  But now this question is marked as "answered", so it will attract less attention, and be less likely to receive a definite answer (if one exists).

Comment: How exactly? I apologize if my previous response didn't meet YOUR expectations. I provided Stephan some troubleshooting steps to help him resolve the issue he was facing with the 429 error in the Instabot library. 
In the future, I kindly suggest you double-check both my answer and the original question to ensure that all relevant information is considered.